# Semantic Versioning - going from one major version to another?

Tags: versioning, semantic-versioning

How should versions be bumped during development between two major versions?
For example let say I have version `1.5.0` and my target is to release new major version that will be incompatible with major version 1.

As soon as I start developing and making changes, those changes will be backwards incompatible, so by following semantic versioning, should I already bump it to `2.0.0`? But development is in progress and code is still unstable.

Or should I bump like any other compatible feature -> `1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.7.0 etc.` and when new major version is ready, just bump to `2.0.0`?

Should it be suffixed with something like `2.0.0-alpha` and then reset `2.0.0`, once it stable? Or bump `1.5.0-alpha` (though does not look right).

P.S. When starting from scratch, it makes sense to start with `0.1.0`, because there is no major version yet, but when there is one, it gets tricky..:)

Comment: You version *releases*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know, what else could I release? But if my release is still not stable, what version should it be?

Comment: You also version "release candidates"

Comment: What do you mean *"what version should it be"*? That question doesn't make sense, because you version what you release (alpha, beta, rc or final - these are all being released). In between, it doesn't *have* a version. In the codebase it'll stay at 1.5.0 during those commits.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> As soon as I start developing and making changes, those changes will be backwards incompatible, so by following semantic versioning, should I already bump it to `2.0.0`? But development is in progress and code is still unstable.

You answer your own question here: "*development is in progress and code is still unstable*", so the code isn't ready for release. Semantic versioning applies to releases, not commits etc. So there is no issue. Your last release remains `1.5.0` until you are ready to release the next version, which is `2.0.0`.

Of course, whilst you are developing, you may wish to release early, pre-release versions. Then you append that fact to the version number, eg `2.0.0-alpha001`, `2.0.0-rc3` etc as required.

Comment: So I guess then, first release (if its not stable release), could be `2.0.0-rc` or `2.0.0-alpha` or whatever? I just got confused by the fact that you start with `0.1.0` and then only bump major version once it is stable (but you still bump unstable releases for `0` major version)

Comment: With CI in use, for any commit can be an internal "release" which should be named somehow and considered by other modules.

Comment: @Andrius, that is correct.`v0` is a special case. After `v1`, pre-releases rely on appending some sort of annotation to the version to reflect that it's a pre-release.  I've updated the answer to reflect that.